# Windows 10 installation on Macbook Air early 2015

Tags: audio, operating-system, windows-10, driver, macbookpro

I've installed the windows 10 on my Macbook Air early 2015 recently and all of the drivers are installed and up to date, even I can adjust volume in the windows task bar but there is no sound and my mac book track pad's right click does not work. drivers of sound card and apple multitouch are installed properly.
Is there any misconfiguration here?? there are some solution on the internet which refer to bootcamp but here I have installed it directly through a live USB flash that i made by Rufus and a windows 10 iso.
I would be so grateful if you could guide me in this regard.
it really makes me disappointed that windows 10 will not work properly on my mabook air 2015.
thank you in advance.